# Couldn't find User with id=#<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_User:0x2eb9b58>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, parameters, userid

I am getting this error when I click on 'edit':

```
Couldn't find User with id=#<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_User:0x2eb9b58> 

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#edit
```

Here is the `UsersController`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :create, :update, :destroy]
  ...
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])  #the error points to this line.
  end
  ...
end
```

FULL TRACE is as follows:

> activerecord (4.0.0)
>   lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:198:in
>   `raise_record_not_found_exception!' activerecord (4.0.0)
>   lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:284:in`find_one'
>   activerecord (4.0.0)
>   lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:268:in `find_with_ids'
>   activerecord (4.0.0)
>   lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:35:in`find'
>   activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
>   lib/active_record/deprecated_finders/relation.rb:122:in `find' C:in`
>   find' app/controllers/users_controller.rb:18:in `edit' actionpack
>   (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in`
>   send_action' actionpack (4.0.0)
>   lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action' actionpack
>   (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in`
>   process_action' actionpack (4.0.0)
>   lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
>   activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in`
>   *run*_759441773__process_action__callbacks' activesupport (4.0.0)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks' actionpack
>   (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in
>   `process_action' actionpack (4.0.0)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in`block in
>   process_action' activesupport (4.0.0)
>   lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
>   activesupport (4.0.0)
>   lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`instrument'
>   activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in
>   `instrument' actionpack (4.0.0)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (4.0.0)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
>   activerecord (4.0.0)
>   lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in`
>   process_action' actionpack (4.0.0)
>   lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process' actionpack (4.0.0)
>   lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in`process' actionpack
>   (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch' actionpack
>   (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in`
>   dispatch' actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in
>   `block in action' actionpack (4.0.0)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in`call' actionpack
>   (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
>   actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in`
>   call' actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in
>   `block in call' actionpack (4.0.0)
>   lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in`each' actionpack (4.0.0)
>   lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call' actionpack (4.0.0)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in`call' rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call' rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in`call' rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call' actionpack (4.0.0)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in`call'
>   actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in
>   `call' rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in`context'
>   rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call' actionpack
>   (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in`call'
>   activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
>   activerecord (4.0.0)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in`
>   call' activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in
>   `call' actionpack (4.0.0)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in`block in call'
>   activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in
>   `_run__847569706__call__callbacks' activesupport (4.0.0)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in`run_callbacks' actionpack
>   (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
>   actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in`
>   call' actionpack (4.0.0)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call' actionpack
>   (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in`
>   call' actionpack (4.0.0)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
>   railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in`call_app' railties
>   (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call' activesupport
>   (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in`block in tagged'
>   activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in
>   `tagged' activesupport (4.0.0)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in`tagged' railties (4.0.0)
>   lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call' actionpack (4.0.0)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in`call' rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call' rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in`call' activesupport (4.0.0)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call' rack
>   (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call' actionpack (4.0.0)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call' railties (4.0.0)
>   lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in`call' railties (4.0.0)
>   lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call' rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call' rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call' rack (1.5.2)
>   lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in`service'
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in
>   `service'
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in`
>   run'
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in
>   `block in start_thread'

Comment: Can you add full REQUEST not only trace?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the view file for the edit command, so `edit.html.erb`. You're likely trying to call something on a join model, instead of the actual object you are trying to display.

Answer (score 1):

You are using controller callback set user for edit. Directly use `@user` instead of finding user object again OR else use find_by method `User.find_by(id: params[:id])`